# Error npm is-core-module in Next JS with Tailwind

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, yarnpkg

After a couple days, when i start my project this error appears:

```
./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/css-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[3].oneOf[8].use[1]!./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/postcss-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[3].oneOf[8].use[2]!./src/styles/globals.css

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\project_is_here\node_modules\is-core-module\index.js'
```

I don't know how fix that, someone can help me?
PS: is like the index file in is-core-module is not created / has been deleted, and don't create another

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and this works for me:

1. Delete from Your **root project directory**:

   - `.next` (folder)
   - `node_modules` (folder) and `package-lock.json` (file)
2. run in terminal `npm cache clean --force` command.
3. run `npm install` command
4. run `npm run dev` command